# HEX to Float - Mid-Little Endian (CDAB) & HEX to (UINT32 - Big Endian (ABCD))

Tags: javascript

I have this data in HEX format 444000d6909b7b2c46bd0006, I need to convert 7b2c46bd in HEX to Float - Mid-Little Endian (CDAB). & 00d6909b in (UINT32 - Big Endian (ABCD)) format can Anyone please suggest what changes should I can made changes in below Script, I created for the HEX to Float(ABCD) data conversion.Thanks in Advance

```html
// // Convert Hex value to float.
function main(a1) {
var b1 = a1;
var d1= b1.substring(4,12);
    var int = parseInt(d1, 16);
    if (int > 0 || int < 0) {
        var sign = (int >>> 31) ? -1 : 1;
        var exp = (int >>> 23 & 0xff) - 127;
        var mantissa = ((int & 0x7fffff) + 0x800000).toString(2);
        var float32 = 0
        for (i = 0; i < mantissa.length; i += 1) { float32 += parseInt(mantissa[i]) ? Math.pow(2, exp) : 0; exp-- }
        var c = float32 * sign;
        }
   else c=0;
return c;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output value and what value are you getting instead?

Comment: Expected value is for 00d6909b-14061723 & 7b2c46bd - 24253.5859   I m getting abrupt values

Answer (score 3):

For the *Mid-Little Endian (CDAB)*, the easiest is probably to go the [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) way *(using its views)*.

First, convert your string to an Uint8Array by simply parsing each components:

```
const hexToUint8 = (str) =>
  Uint8Array
    .from( str.match( /.{1,2}/g )
      .map( (comp) => parseInt( comp, 16 ) )
    );
```

Then swap AB and CD

```
const [ A, B, C, D ] = hexToUint8( str );
const reordered = new Uint8Array( [ C, D, A, B ] );
```

Finally read that as Float32

```
const res = new DataView( reordered.buffer ).getFloat32( 0 );
```

```js
const hexToUint8 = (str) =>
  Uint8Array
    .from( str.match( /.{1,2}/g )
      .map( (comp) => parseInt( comp, 16 ) )
    );

const hex = "7b2c46bd";

const [ A, B, C, D ] = hexToUint8( hex );
const reordered = new Uint8Array( [ C, D, A, B ] );

const res = new DataView( reordered.buffer ).getFloat32( 0 );
console.log( res );
```

For the ABCD case, you can also go this route, without the swapping:

```js
const hexToUint8 = (str) =>
  Uint8Array
    .from( str.match( /.{1,2}/g )
      .map( (comp) => parseInt( comp, 16 ) )
    );

const hex = "00d6909b";

const uint8 = hexToUint8( hex );

const res = new DataView( uint8.buffer ).getUint32( 0 );
console.log( res );
```

Or even try `Number( "0x" + hex )`.

```js
const hex = "00d6909b";
const res = Number( '0x' + hex );
console.log( res );
```

Comment: I needed to convert hex data to Uint32 Mid-Little Endian (CDAB) and your code worked as expected with a small change: instead of `getFloat32()` I used `getUint32()`, i.e. `new DataView(reordered.buffer).getUint32(0)`. Thanks, @Kaiido! … Also, instead of `hexToUint8()`, one could use `new Uint8Array(buffer)` when `hex` is a `Buffer` instead of a `String`.